# Confusion about Covariance Matrix

Tags: pca, covariance

I often [read](https://www.mii.lt/zilinskas/uploads/visualization/lectures/lect14/comparison.pdf) [that](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc541.htm) the covariance matrix is calculated $C = BB^T$; however, I also [read](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147880/is-pca-still-done-via-the-eigendecomposition-of-the-covariance-matrix-when-dimen/147983#147983) that it is $C = B^TB$, which I thought was the Gram matrix.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yes: you need to pay attention to notational conventions and definitions.  Some people use the transposes of others' matrices.  Thus, an expression like "$BB^\prime$" is inherently ambiguous until you explain what it represents.

Comment: I gotcha, so you cannot simple say $C = BB^T$ without explaining the matrix $B$?

Comment: Yes: are the variables in columns or are they in rows of $B$?

Comment: Right, this makes perfect sense. Thanks. I'll go shoot my foot now.

Comment: This is one of the wonderful things about statistics: everybody sees value in it but different communities have developed different languages and notational systems for describing what they are doing ;-).  The statistical literature tends to put variables into columns while many computing-oriented communities use rows.

Comment: If columns of $B$ are variables (and rows are cases) and columns are centered, $X'X$ is the scatter matrix and $XX'$ is sometimes called Gram matrix.